# Integration Testing FilterAttribute with IExceptionFilter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5, custom-attributes

I am working with `.Net 4.5`, `C#`, `MVC 5` website.

I am trying to write a test to see if mechanism that is supposed to fire `FilterAttribute` that is supposed to log errors works.

**Attribute:**

```
public class LogErrorsAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext != null && filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            var area = filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] as string;
            var controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            var action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
            var httpMethod = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod;
            var loggerName = string.Format("Area - {0}, {1}Controller.{2} method {3}", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(area) ? "none" : area, controller, action, httpMethod);
            var model = filterContext.Controller != null && filterContext.Controller.TempData!= null ? filterContext.Controller.TempData["model"] : null;
            //log here
            MvcApplication.Logger.Error(new ErrorLogEntry {Error = filterContext.Exception, Summary = loggerName, Data = model });
        }
    }
```

What I am having hard time with making `OnException` to fire from mocked Context

**Test:**

```
[TestFixture]
public class ControllerTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestCompleteControllerErrorLoggingSystem()
    {
        var httpCtxStub = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var controller = new CompleteController();
        var controllerCtx = new ControllerContext
        {
            Controller = controller,
            RequestContext = new RequestContext(httpCtxStub.Object, new RouteData())
        };

        controllerCtx.HttpContext = httpCtxStub.Object;

        controller.ControllerContext = controllerCtx; 
        var sessionId = Guid.NewGuid();
        controller.LeafManagerConfirmation(6868, 99M, "sdfsdfs", sessionId.ToString(), "Will", "CN");

    }
}
```

**Controller part that is being tested:**

```
    public async void LeafManagerConfirmation(int leafTransId, decimal amount, string paymentReference, string sessionId, string productType, string cn)
    {
        //Update the Journey
        using (var db = new OnlineLegal())
        {
            var completedTransaction = db.Journey.SingleOrDefault(o => o.BarclaysTransactionRef == paymentReference);
            if (completedTransaction != null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Duplicate transaction recorded: leafId {0}, amount {1}, paymentReference {2}",
                    leafTransId, amount, paymentReference));
            }
    }
```

Reference that I am passing does exist in database so it always fires `InvalidOperationException` and test is good up until this point, however `OnException` in `FilterAttribute` does not get fired (error simply gets 'swallowed' when looking from the test), and I am guessing it's because of `HttpContextBase` being mocked context.

If I am correct on this, **how do I need to change `HttpContextBase` mock so that it would fire `OnException` on `LogErrorsAttribute`?**

**If it's not because of `HttpContextBase` where did I go wrong?**